# BinaryFormatter.Serialize( Image ) - ExternalException - A generic error occurred in GDI+

Tags: c#, gdi+

When I try to Serialize *some* images using the BinaryFormatter, I'll get a ExternalException - A generic error occurred in GDI+." After scratching my head for awhile, I decided to create a simple test project to narrow down the problem:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string file = @"C:\temp\delme.jpg";

        //Image i = new Bitmap(file);
        //using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))

        byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
        using(MemoryStream originalms = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            using (Image i = Image.FromStream(originalms))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    // Throws ExternalException on Windows 7, not Windows XP
                    bf.Serialize(ms, i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For specific images, I've tried all sorts of ways of loading the image and I could not get it to work under Windows 7, even when running the program as Administrator.

I've copied the exact same executable and image into my Windows XP VMWare instance and I have no problems.

Anyone have any idea of why for some images it doesn't work under Windows 7, but works under XP?

---

Here's one of the images:
http://www.2shared.com/file/7wAXL88i/SO_testimage.html

delme.jpg md5: 3d7e832db108de35400edc28142a8281

Comment: Please provide one of the problematic images (upload it somewhere and give us the link).

Comment: Hi can you please select the post that best addressed your needs as the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the OP pointed out, the code provided throws an exception that seems to be occurring only with the image he provided but works fine with other images on my machine.

**Option 1**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string file = @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\delme.jpg";

    byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
    using (MemoryStream originalms = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        using (Image i = Image.FromStream(originalms))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Throws ExternalException on Windows 7, not Windows XP                        
                //bf.Serialize(ms, i);

                i.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp); // Works
                i.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png); // Works
                i.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg); // Fails
            }    
         }
     }
}
```

It could be that the image in question was created with a tool that added some additional information that is interfering with the JPEG serialization.

P.S. The image *can* be saved to memory stream using **BMP** or **PNG** format. If changing the format is an option, then you can try out either of these or any other format defined in **ImageFormat**.

**Option 2**
If your goal is just to get the contents of the image file into a memory stream, then doing just the following would help

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string file = @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\delme.jpg";
    using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(file))
    {
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        memStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
        fileStream.Read(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that another solution was to create a copy of the Image and serialize that, but since that wasn't acceptable (since some images can be very large), I ended up rewriting the code and other methods to completely remove the serialization. A lot of work for simply running the Project on Win7 instead of WinXP. :[

Answer (score 2):

Although the `Bitmap` class is marked as `[Serializable]`, it does not actually support serialisation. The best you can do is serialise the `byte[]` containing the raw image data and then re-create it using a `MemoryStream` and the `Image.FromStream()` method.

I can't explain the inconsistent behaviour you're experiencing; for me, it fails unconditionally (although I first discovered this when trying to marshal images between different app domains, rather than manually serialising them).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure but I would lean towards different security models for XP vs Windows 7. Image inherits from System.MarshalByRefObject. There is probably proxying going on between application domains when serialization is performed. This proxying might be forbidden in Windows 7.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject%28v=vs.71%29.aspx