# How to bound images to a save file?

Tags: c#, image, save

Similar to when a ms word file has images in it, the image isn't shown externally.

So far, my application only could save the image path using xmlserializer, so, when the image is removed, the image in the saved file is also missing.

How to create a saving method so the image file ia also bound the file? Doesn't strictly need to use xmlserializer though.

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907077/serialize-a-bitmap-in-c-net-to-xml) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841690/serialize-and-store-an-image-in-an-xml-file) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15916661/binaryformatter-serialize-image-externalexception-a-generic-error-occurre) ? Serialzation of some kind probably is the way to go. Or you could add a header of your own to the byte array to hold any further data and write it out as a binary file.. What kind of data will you write in addition to the image?

Comment: Seems i haven't see those article. Since i cant find the proper keyword to express it. Hmm. The data is just a plain data such as string, double, int, etc. And also possibly class serialization in the next step of the development.