# C# WPF convert Image to object and back

Tags: c#, image, object

This is an evolution of:
[C# image binary serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801746/c-sharp-image-binary-serialization)

I have very simple class:

```
public class TheClass2
{
   public object myImg;
   public int myInt;
}
```

In order to serialize it I have to cast myImg from image to object

```
var ist = new TheClass2();
Image i = new Image();
ist.myImg= Convert.ChangeType(i, typeof(object));<-----this is not working
```

but ist.myImg is still an image.

Thanx for any help
Patrick

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what the `Convert.ChangeType()` method does. Where did you get the idea that it would _serialize_ your data? As explained in your previous question, you will need to save your image data explicitly in a format appropriate to your scenario. There are lots of ways to do this, all documented on MSDN and described in various Q&As on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I was wrong. So easy in the end:

```
public class MyBitmapImage
{
        public string strBitmapImage;
        public bool IsImageEmbedded;
}
```

and then serialize as:

```
public static bool FileSerializer<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, out string strError, bool append = false)
{
  using (Stream fileStream = File.Open(filePath, append ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create))
  {
    strError = string.Empty;
    try
    {
      var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
      binaryFormatter.Serialize(fileStream, objectToWrite);
      return true;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
      strError = "Binary FileSerializer exception:" + exc;
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```